# how to convert a php script into a phar file?

Tags: php, phar

The goal of the project is to convert a php script into .phar

My project is made of : 
**1 single index.php that calls classes into /lib and /database** folders

the goal is to have as less files as possible to distribute (ideally 2 : index.php and assets.phar which will include all files from /lib and /database) or even 1 (index.phar)

I tried with empir with any success: has someone has done that before ?

Any tutorial available ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [the `Phar` class](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.phar.php). For example, put this in `compress.php`:

```
$phar = new Phar('index.phar');
$phar->addFile('index.php');
$phar->buildFromDirectory('lib');
$phar->buildFromDirectory('database');
```

Run `php compress.php` from the command line. Voilà, you have yourself a Phar.

Comment: and how do I use this phar file ? How to execute it ?

Comment: @user300675: PHP should be able to run it as any other PHP file. I tried Pharring up a little PHP script I knew worked on the command line and ran the result with `php index.phar` and it worked as normal. Things should work similarly smoothly on a web server if you configure it to recognize `.phar` as PHP.

Answer (score 4):

I use the following script:

```
<?php
$phar = new \Phar(__DIR__ . '/index.phar');    
$phar->startBuffering(); // For performance reasons. Ordinarily, every time a file within a Phar archive is created or modified in any way, the entire Phar archive will be recreated with the changes.  
$phar->addFile('index.php');
$phar->addFile('composer.json');
$phar->addFile('composer.lock');
$phar->buildFromDirectory(__DIR__ . '/vendor');
$phar->stopBuffering();
```

Run the following command to run the previous script:

```
$ php -dphar.readonly=0 index.php
```

(Creating of phar archives is disabled by default in PHP.)